# Out of Memory error in Kitkat and not in Lollipop

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing an android application.

When I ran the application in Kitkat and monitoring the memory using IntelliJ Idea's Memory monitor, I found that it used atleast than 65 mb at runtime.

But when I ran it in Lollipop, I found that it used only around 35 mb at runtime.

After running for sometime, say 15 mins, the application crashed in Kitkat. Not in Lollipop.. On examining, I found an out of memory situation at the native level. To be exact, in the class BasicHashtable.cpp of the android platform.

Any idea why this happens in Kitkat and not in Lollipop ?

Comment: Possibly a different heap size.

Comment: Infact , i have given android:largeHeap = true in both the cases.. Anyways, shouldn't the application demand the same heap size in both kitkat and lollipop ?

Comment: There is no guarantee in Android what size heap you will get, or whether large heap does anything.  Read this.https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html.  The correct answer is to reduce your heap usage.